# Entity Framework with Oracle AND SQL (switch automatically)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, oracle, entity-framework

I maintain an asp.net MVC application which uses Entity Framework (database first) and connects to an oracle database.

**My question:**
How can I switch between oracle and SQL server using entity framework?

The meaning has the ability to get data from both oracle and SQL server.  Also, the switch from oracle to SQL server (if it is possible) should be automated.

After a search, I found that I can switch between oracle and SQL server in the same app by:

1. Creating repositories for 2 models
2. Using mapping with 2 .edmx files. In this way, one of them will generate the code of model and entity classes and the other is used as a source of XML resources.

Also, I found other useful info but they are all very general.

**How do** I convert oracle edmx to the sql_server equivalent?

During my search, I migrated my oracle database using Microsoft's SSMA to an SQL server database so now I have the same database in oracle and also in SQL SERVER.

Does someone knows the steps to get me a bit closer to solution?

Comment: you mean how to convert one model lets call it oracleX to one equivalent model sqlX, or you want the whole database to be converted ?

Comment: The whole database..I used Microsoft migration tool SSMA and  migrated the whole database to an sql server database because i was thinking i must have the same exact mapping and of course data..But the next steps are a bit unknown for me

Comment: I am still not sure what you want, what is the next step exactly ? 
you want generic way to add the same data as 2 different model into 2 different databases ? 
is that it ?

Comment: i 've edited the question post